# how to access properties passed to Ember Component inside a component-class?

Tags: ember.js, properties, components

I have DECLARED an emberjs component in template as:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" id="components/custom-component">      
  <h4>The name of the object passed is : {{object.name}}</h4>
  {{#if show_details}}
    <p>The details of the object passed are : {{object.details}}</p>
  {{/if}}
</script>
```

Now I am USING this component in my html template as :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <ul>
    {{#each object in model}}
      <li>{{custom-component object=object}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</script>
```

My component class for custom-component is as shown below :

```
App.CustomComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
  show_details: function() {
      // return true or false based on the OBJECT's property (e.g. "true" if object.type is 'AUTHORIZED')
  },
});
```

**Update**

The way I achieved it is as follows :

```
App.CustomComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    show_details: function() {
      var object = this.get('object');
      if (object.type == "AUTHORIZED")
        return true;
      else
        return false;
    }
});
```

The parameters passed to the component class are available using it's `get` methods.

Answer (score 6):

It should work this way:

```
{{custom-component object_name=object}}
```

(you just used the wrong property name).

This should work if `object` is the object name. If name is a property of `object` then use `object.name`.

---

**UPDATE**

This should be straightforward. `show_details` should be defined as computed property depending on the `object type`:

```
App.CustomComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    object: null,
    show_details: function() {
      var object = this.get('object');
      if (object.get('type') === "AUTHORIZED")
         return true;
      else
         return false;
    }.property('object.type') 
});
```

or simpler:

```
App.CustomComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
    show_details: function() {
      return this.get('object').get('type') === "AUTHORIZED";
    }.property('object.type') 
});
```

Don't forget to use `get` when accessing the properties of an Ember object.

Comment: Thank you @splattne for your answer. But what I am looking for is I would want my custom-component to have a property which depends on on one of the properties of the object that is passed to the component. Would you please have look at updated question and let me know your views on the same?

Comment: So you need to define a method in the component when you pass in a variable? And the value of is the default value? The guides don't say whether you need to explicitly declare the variable in the component when one is passed in.

Comment: So if you pass in a variable, you have to define the attribute used in tge parent te.plate as a method in the component? The guides don't say whether you need to explicitly declare the variable in the component when one is passed in. And is tgebvalue u used, null, simply the default value?

Answer (score 0):

Updated for **Glimmer Components**

In the newer Ember components (Glimmer), you can access the values passed to the  components inside the component class from `this.args`. The guide [here](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/upgrading/current-edition/glimmer-components/#toc_arguments) is very helpful.

Simple example from the guide

Before:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { computed } from '@ember/object';

export default Component.extend({
  width: 0,
  height: 0,

  aspectRatio: computed('width', 'height', function() {
    return this.width / this.height;
  })
});
```

```
{{!-- Usage --}}
<Image @width="1920" @height="1080" />
```

After:

```js
import Component from '@glimmer/component';

export default class ImageComponent extends Component {
  get aspectRatio() {
    return this.args.width / this.args.height;
  }
}
```

```
{{!-- Usage --}}
<Image @width="1920" @height="1080" />
```